# C# SendGrid using-direktive missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package, sendgrid

I installed the SendGrid package, but I get the following using-direktive missing error. (Our project runs on .NET Framework 4.5.2)

The type or namespace name 'SendGridMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

The type or namespace name 'Web' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using AWE.Models;
using SendGrid;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
 {
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        return configSendGridasync(message);
    }
    private Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S.");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["awe7"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't view the images. Can you copy the relevant information into the question?

Comment: Do not show your code in pictures. Put it as text in your question. And show the exact error message you're getting. Squiggly lines don't tell us much.

Comment: What happens if you click on the red squiggles and press CTRL+. ?

Comment: You're missing `using System.Configuration;` so of course `ConfigurationManager` doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to install Resharper

Comment: Not that it's not worth every single penny, but not everyone has over a $100 to just drop on Resharper. Check to make sure that you have System.ConfigurationManager referenced in the project. Should fix the issue.

Comment: System.Configuration solved the ConfigurationManager problem. Thanks for that. But I'm still facing the "SendGridMessage" and "Web" error.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the issue and get it working.. and it's actually very simple: **just make sure you don't install the latest SendGrid version, but go with v6.1.0**. However, this might also indicate that SendGrid is going into a new direction.. let me know whether it worked for you.

Comment: To give a little more information the break was version v7.  You can install up to v6.3.4 using this syntax.